# A datablock to join a single result with multiple other results

Tags: c#, .net, tpl-dataflow

In my application I want to join multiple strings with a dictionary of replacement values.

The `readTemplateBlock` gets fed with FileInfos and returns their contents as string.
The `getReplacersBlock` gets fed (once) with a single replacers dictionary.
The `joinTemplateAndReplacersBlock` should join each item of the `readTemplateBlock` with the one `getReplacersBlock` result.

In my current setup it requires me to post the same replacers dictionary again for each file I post.

```
// Build
var readTemplateBlock = new TransformBlock<FileInfo, string>(file => File.ReadAllText(file.FullName));
var getReplacersBlock = new WriteOnceBlock<IDictionary<string, string>>(null);
var joinTemplateAndReplacersBlock = new JoinBlock<string, IDictionary<string, string>>();

// Assemble
var propagateComplete = new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true};

readTemplateBlock.LinkTo(joinTemplateAndReplacersBlock.Target1, propagateComplete);
getReplacersBlock.LinkTo(joinTemplateAndReplacersBlock.Target2, propagateComplete);
joinTemplateAndReplacersBlock.LinkTo(replaceTemplateBlock, propagateComplete);

// Post
foreach (var template in templateFilenames)
{
    getFileBlock.Post(template);
}
getFileBlock.Complete();

getReplacersBlock.Post(replacers);
getReplacersBlock.Complete();
```

Is there a better block I'm missing? Maybe a configuration option I overlooked?

Comment: Have you considered using a `TaskCompletionSource` for the dictionary, instead of `WriteOnceBlock` and `JoinBlock`?

Comment: Never heard of them. Will research

Comment: could you elaborate and maybe turn into a answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to do this using the built-in dataflow blocks. The alternatives I can see:

1. Use a `BufferBlock` with small `BoundedCapacity` along with a `Task` that keeps sending the value to it. How exactly does the `Task` get the value could vary, but if you like `WriteOnceBlock`, you could reuse and encapsulate it:

   ```
   static IPropagatorBlock<T, T> CreateWriteOnceRepeaterBlock<T>()
   {
       var target = new WriteOnceBlock<T>(null);
       var source = new BufferBlock<T>(new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 1 });

       Task.Run(
           async () =>
           {
               var value = await target.ReceiveAsync();

               while (true)
               {
                   await source.SendAsync(value);
               }
           });

       return DataflowBlock.Encapsulate(target, source);
   }
   ```

   You would then use `CreateWriteOnceRepeaterBlock<IDictionary<string, string>>()` instead of `new WriteOnceBlock<IDictionary<string, string>>(null)`.
2. Write a custom block similar to `WriteOnceBlock` that behaves exactly the way you want. Looking at how big [the source of `WriteOnceBlock`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Blocks/WriteOnceBlock.cs) is, this is probably not very appealing.
3. Use a `TaskCompletionSource` instead of dataflow blocks for this.

   Assuming your current code looks something like this (using C# 7 and the `System.ValueTuple` package for brevity):

   ```
   void ReplaceTemplateBlockAction(Tuple<string, IDictionary<string, string>> tuple)
   {
       var (template, replacers) = tuple;
       …
   }

   …

   var getReplacersBlock = new WriteOnceBlock<IDictionary<string, string>>(null);
   var replaceTemplateBlock = new ActionBlock<Tuple<string, IDictionary<string, string>>>(
       ReplaceTemplateBlockAction);
   …
   getReplacersBlock.Post(replacers);
   ```

   You would instead use:

   ```
   void ReplaceTemplateBlockAction(string template, IDictionary<string, string>>> replacers)
   {
       …
   }

   …

   var getReplacersTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IDictionary<string, string>>();
   var replaceTemplateBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(
       async template => ReplaceTemplateBlockAction(template, await getReplacersTcs.Task));
   …
   getReplacersTcs.SetResult(replacers);
   ```

Comment: I went with the taskcompletionsource. It turned out to make a lot of things much simpler